# Help to identify author please

Tags: art

[![Who is that author][1]][1]
Here are the seals
Please review photos

[chop][2]][2]

Zoomed in
Please let me know
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJZHW.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFyK3.jpg

Comment: the 2nd picture is “治”

Answer (score 2):

The first seal in the first picture is 鄧 and the second one seems like 紅雾.  with the second character being a more simplified version of the simplified 霧 --> 雾 (mist); It could also be another version of the simplified 霞, thus making it 紅霞 (the same 紅霞 in the writing) instead of 紅霧 I presumed

I am pretty sure the author's last name is 鄧.

紅雾 or 紅霞 is most likely her first name or pen name

水巷孑蠻 wrote:

> The 2nd picture is “治”

I have no objection

As for the writing, I can only make out the larger text on the right "深秋峽紅霞" = "Red clouds in the late autumn gorge"

**Edit:**

After searching both 鄧紅霞 and 鄧紅雾, I found this Artist [鄧紅霞](https://%20https://baike.baidu.hk/item/%E9%84%A7%E7%B4%85%E9%9C%9E/58670052)

> 鄧紅霞，女，現為法國當代藝術家協會會員，美國當代中國畫研究會會員

> Deng Hongxia, female, is currently a member of the French Association of Contemporary Artists and a member of the American Contemporary Chinese Painting Research Association.

After looking at her art on the page, I didn't see any painting with a similar style to the painting you posted. And she doesn't use seals or Chinese in any of the paintings. It might just be a coincidence